# Alter table with substring?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The Title of the Customer is Located in the CustomerFname Column. Separate the title into its own column and also retrieve CustomerFname, CustomerLname, City, State and LoanDate of Loans that are more than 1 yr old.

I need to separate Mr, Mrs, and Dr from first Name column into its own title column. Second get the customer first name, last name, city, state, and loan date for loan more than a year old.

Here is the table

[image: 1]

----First part of question-------

```
SUBSTRING(CustomerFname,0, 4) AS Title
FROM [dbo].[Loan]
```

----This is what I have tried---- got an error----

```
ALTER TABLE SUBSTRING(CustomerFname,0, 4) AS Title, [CustomerFname], [CustomerLname], [City], [State], [LoanDate] 
FROM [dbo].[Loan]
```

Comment: Check [Add Columns to a Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/add-columns-to-a-table-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) and [Specify Computed Columns in a Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16). You need to tell `ALTER TABLE` what operation to perform. In this case `ADD` a column, eg `ALTER TABLE Loan ADD Title AS LEFT(CustomerFname,4)`

Comment: you probably also don't want to hardcode in the number of characters to substring by, I suspect you'll want to use CHARINDEX within the third argument for SUBSTRING

Comment: its still in the customer first name after execution, I need to permanently modify the table

Answer (score 0):

As @Panagiotis Kanavos said you can do like so :

```
ALTER TABLE Loan ADD Title AS LEFT(CustomerFname,CHARINDEX('.',CustomerFname))
```

Then you would have to update your names with :

```
UPDATE Loan
SET CustomerFname = LTRIM(RIGHT(CustomerFname,LEN(CustomerFname)-CHARINDEX('.',CustomerFname))
```

If you want your field [Title] to be at a specific position in table you would have to delete and recreate the table.

For the second part

```
SELECT * FROM Loan WHERE LoanDate < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
```